# convert type 'Tile' to 'Tile[]'

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I am getting the error `cannot implicitly convert type 'Tile' to type 'Tile[]'.` in the following code:

```cs
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Tile[,] AllTiles = new Tile [4,4];

    void Start()
    {
        // Error: cannot implicitly convert type 'Tile' to type 'Tile[]'.
        Tile[] AllTilesOnDim = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<Tile>();
        foreach (Tile t in AllTilesOnDim)
        {
            t.Number = 0;
            AllTiles[t.indRow, t.indCol]= t;
        }
    }
}
```

and there are an other class :

```cs
public class Tile : MonoBehaviour
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: You must use `FindObjectsOfType` not `FindObjectOfType`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `FindObjectsOfType` not `FindObjectOfType`!

Also read about it at this link : [Object.FindObjectsOfType](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectsOfType.html).

Comment: @issamjallal You can accept this answer to help others.